# Telerik ASP.NET MVC extensions multiple charts in one view rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 and am trying to create a view that has 3 Telerik graphs and a calendar. 1 chart is a pie chart, 1 is a line graph, and 1 is an area chart.

Everything loads perfectly the first time, but when you reload the page, every chart only loads a portion of each chart. None of them are completely rendered on reload.